# Can the limitations of Mind Thrust be overcome?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

The Mind Thrust psionic power has a few disadvantages.

Notably, it is mind-affecting, which doesn't allow it to function against undead, constructs, oozes, and some plant creatures.

Also, it requires a will save, which if made, negates all damage.

Some might argue that power points are also a limitation, but that is beyond the intent of my question.

What methods can help it overcome these two constraints?:

- affect the mindless
- either remove the will save, or boost the save DC.

Comment: If this was answerable, the Beguiler would be a much better class than it is currently considered to be. I conclude that this is not answerable.

Comment: @J.Mini then it will either get answered that way or it will hang out unanswered.  Either is fine.